# Angular blink when changes detected

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, angular, typescript

i've got array of objects from backend and I am wondering if its possible to apply css effects to updated element.

For example:

```
   let arr = [
  {
    "value": "1234"
  },
  {
    "value": "12345"
  },
  {
    "value": "12346"
  }
]



   <div *ngFor="let item of arr;>
    <span>{{item.id}}<span>
    </div>
```

And I want to blink or something when value are changed. Thanks!

Comment: Angular 9 of course

Comment: create a boolean before http request as `false`, and change it inside subscription (when you receive the data) to `true`. Then change the CSS class for your `<div>` with some if statement using that boolean. Or just trigger a one time animation class with `setTimeout`  only when you receive the data

Comment: But i want to blink specific span, not all of them ;>

Comment: find the index of the modified element (maybe with something like `array1.indexOf(array1.filter(x => !array2.includes(x))[0])`, with `array1` as an old array and `array2` your modified one), then extend *ngFor with index values: `*ngFor="let item of arr; let i = index"`, and then change the class of the `<span>` with the right index